# Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on object

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

IAM HAVING THIS ERROR, i imported firebase to my flutter project and now it cannot configure it...

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/742WY.png)
[This is my code and it has the latest plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1wmn.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle file in root project>android>app>build.gradle
you found id for this error
change it to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

before android{} tag and delete id plugin